# How to use Sugar ORM?

Tags: android, database, sugarorm

I am developing one application and now I need to use database in my application. I wanna use Sugar ORM, but I didn't find "actual" documentation and "actual" version on Maven (I found 1.3 and 1.4 versions). Can somebody share information or links about Sugar ORM?

For example, when I create a model I take error cause class SugarRecord doesn't exist

Comment: If SugarRecord class doesn't exist, the problem could be a wrong library import or a missing `import` statement in your class (where you refer SugarRecod)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find all informations in the [Getting started documentation](https://satyan.github.io/sugar/getting-started.html). For the maven repository see [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.satyan/sugar) .

Comment: I used it, but took a lot of errors. It's for version 1.3
I meant version for connect library to project throught gradle from maven repositories

Comment: Probably you should use 1.3 version, since [1.4 is in beta](https://github.com/satyan/sugar/releases) and, as always, the main documentation talks about latest stable version.

Comment: I have founded this veriosn. But take error:
Error:(7, 9) Attribute application@icon value=(@mipmap/icon) from AndroidManifest.xml:7:9

Comment: Thanks) Add it. But now take NullPointerException when try to save(

Comment: Okay, I have fixed it just add to manifest this: android:name="com.orm.SugarApp". And I have one more question about Sugar ORM. Can I use it in my commercial projects and if I can - I need to add some license file or no?

Comment: _The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be
included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software._

Comment: See the complete [License file (MIT)](https://github.com/satyan/sugar/blob/master/LICENSE).

MIT license allow commercial use, but you must give credits. For example you could use [a dedicated view](http://androidsha.blogspot.it/2014/06/include-open-source-software-license.html) like many android apps.

Comment: So, I just need to create some view with this text https://github.com/satyan/sugar/blob/master/LICENSE, right?

Comment: Yes, you could create a "Legal notice" menu item that open the view with the text "This product includes software from the Sugar ORM project by Satya Narayan" followed by the entire license text. Please accept the main answer if it was useful and, if you need more help with the license, ask another question since we're going off-topic. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just one moment: this view may be call from settings or about?

Comment: I think that a button "Legal notice" inside the "About" view/menu would be ok.

Comment: Thank for your answer

Answer (score 2):

You can follow the simple steps in this webiste:
http://satyan.github.io/sugar/

I'm assuming you are using Android Studio, add this line to your build.gradle (Module app) file under dependencies.
compile 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.4'

Then add the following lines to your AndroidManifest file:

```html
<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon"
android:name="com.orm.SugarApp">
.
.
<meta-data android:name="DATABASE" android:value="sugar_example.db" />
<meta-data android:name="VERSION" android:value="2" />
<meta-data android:name="QUERY_LOG" android:value="true" />
<meta-data android:name="DOMAIN_PACKAGE_NAME" android:value="com.example" />
.
.
</application>
```

Then all your object classes must extend SugarRecord.

When you create a new object, it creates the entity by itself.
Remember to add an empty constructor because for some reason, if you dont have it wont store it. Also remember to add the permissions required in case you are reading from the internet a JSON service.
Once you have an object created, you can use .save() to store it in the datebase, but when you update use .commit()

The oficial steps are in their website:
http://satyan.github.io/sugar/getting-started.html

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

First install the sugar orm by adding the line below to your to your module level gradle dependencies and then sync your project:

```
compile 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.5'
```

You then have to specify SugarApp as your application class by changing the android name attribute in your application tag. Also, you need to include some meta data about your database such as your database name, version etc. Your manifest file should look something like this:

```
<application
        android:name="com.orm.SugarApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data android:name="DATABASE" android:value="sugar_example.db" />
        <meta-data android:name="VERSION" android:value="1" />
        <meta-data android:name="QUERY_LOG" android:value="true" />
        <meta-data android:name="DOMAIN_PACKAGE_NAME" android:value="com.kwabenaberko" />
    </application>
```

All your data models that you want to persist need to extend SugarRecord and also have at least an empty default constructor:

```
import com.orm.SugarRecord;

public class Developer extends SugarRecord{
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String favouriteLanguage;

    public Developer(){

    }

    public Developer(String firstname, String lastname, String favouriteLanguage){
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.favouriteLanguage = favouriteLanguage;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public String getFavouriteLanguage() {
        return favouriteLanguage;
    }

    public void setFavouriteLanguage(String favouriteLanguage) {
        this.favouriteLanguage = favouriteLanguage;
    }
}
```

Then insert a new record like this:

```
Developer developer = new Developer("Kwabena", "Berko", "JavaScript");
developer.save();
```

I wrote an article on https://dev.to, describing the use of Sugar ORM in much more detail:
https://dev.to/kwabenberko/sugar-orm-an-easier-way-to-work-with-sqlite-databases-in-android-cpg